# Send an email using email addresses from a column in Google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create code that will send an email using addresses from a specific column in google sheets.  I want the code to send an email after the sheet is edited by other users.  For example, someone enters a request on a row in the sheet - then an email is sent to the manager of the request.  Here's what I have so far...

```
function SendEmail(){
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HLP REQUESTS").getRange("K:K");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues()[0][0];
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'A request has been submitted for professional learning related to an HLP you champion.  Please check the Design Team Notes document in case follow-up is required.'; // Second column
var subject = 'HLP Request for Professional Learning';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

When I run the code above I get an error -  Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient.  There is a valid email address in column K, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Can you show how the cell 'K1' looks like in the sheet 'HLP REQUESTS'?

Comment: K1 is empty (it's a header row).  The email addresses are in column K, starting at K3.

Comment: I just updated the range to "K3:K1000" and it seems to work!  Is there a way to add a line of code that will only send emails to the email in the last row?

Comment: It can be done pretty easy, see my answer. By the way the range can be 'K3:K' (without 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want get email address from the last cell of the column K it can be done this way:

```
function SendEmail(){
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("HLP REQUESTS").getRange("K:K");

  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues()
    .flat()           // convert a 2d array into a flat array
    .filter(String)   // remove empty elements from the array
    .pop();           // get the last element from the array

  var message = 'A request has been submitted for professional learning related to an HLP you champion.  Please check the Design Team Notes document in case follow-up is required.';
  var subject = 'HLP Request for Professional Learning';

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

**Update**

Here is the full implementation with installable trigger `onEdit` that sends email as soon as the checkbox (in column L) was checked in:

```
// global variables
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get the srpreadsheet
var checkbox_col = 12;                          // column with checkboxes (L in this case)

// the main function
function sendEmail(e) {
  try {
    var {rowStart, columnStart} = e.range;   // get row and column of the cell that was edited
    if (columnStart != checkbox_col) return; // do nothing if it was not column with checkboxes
    if (e.value != 'TRUE') return;           // do nothing if the checkboxs was unchecked
    e.range.setValue(false);                 // else uncheck the chekbox
        
    var sheet = SS.getSheetByName('HLP REQUESTS');                // get the sheet
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange('K' + rowStart).getValue(); // get email addres from current row, column K

    var message = 'A request has been submitted for professional learning related to an HLP you champion. Please check the Design Team Notes document in case follow-up is required.';
    var subject = 'HLP Request for Professional Learning';

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);       // send the message
    SS.toast('Email to ' + emailAddress + ' has been sent');
  } 
  catch(e) { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e) }
}


// additional functions -------------------------------------------------------------------------

// insatll the trigger
function install_onEidt_trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail').forSpreadsheet(SS).onEdit().create();
  SS.toast('Trigger was installed');
}

// remove all triggers
function remove_all_triggers() {
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  SS.toast('All triggers were remoded');
}

// custom menu to install and remove triggers
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⚙️ Scripts')
  .addItem('Install trigger', 'install_onEidt_trigger')
  .addItem('Remove all triggers', 'remove_all_triggers')
  .addToUi();
}
```

To make it work you have:

- to reload the spreadsheet (or to run the function `onEdit()` manually) to get the custom menu **Scripts**
- in the custom menu run the item **Install trigger**
- after that it will try to send the message to the address from column K of current row whenever user clicks on checkbox in column L

My test sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly!  If I set up a trigger for the function to run on edit - I won't need to do anything else, correct?

Comment: Unfortunately the simply `onEdit` trigger can't send emails due security reasons. It can be done if you (or a user of the script) install the trigger. It will need an additional step.

Comment: I installed the trigger to run every day from 7-8 AM.  I think I didn't communicate it right above... I only want it to email my managers when a new row is added.  So, instead of emailing the last row, I want it to email when a row is added.

Comment: How exactly the last rows will be added? Manually or by another script?

Comment: Rows are populated by multiple users.  When they have a request, they find the next available row and add their information.

Comment: I'd propose to add a column with chekboxes. It will send email as soon as a user click on the checkbox. Or/and a script should check if all the cells of the row are filled and in this case send an email.

Comment: I have a column with a checkbox to be checked when the user is ready to submit.  Would this work?  If so, how would I modify the code above to use this column as the variable for sending the email?

Comment: So you have users that fill the table and click on the checkboxes to send message to email address that place in current row in column K. Correct?

Comment: Exactly!  I've been trying to add a line of code that will only send the emails to address in column K when when the checkbox in column H is clicked, but I'm not very proficient with java yet.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just added the full implementation of the code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This is amazing!  I really appreciate all the help, and that you put comments in the code so I can see what the lines are doing - that's great for me since I'm learning.  Thank you SO much!

Answer (score 0):

#### Sending Emails

```
function SendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const rsh = ss.getSheetByName("HLP REQUESTS");
  const emails = rsh.getRange("K1:K" + rsh.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  var message = 'A request has been submitted for professional learning related to an HLP you champion.  Please check the Design Team Notes document in case follow-up is required.';
  var subject = 'HLP Request for Professional Learning';
  emails.forEach(e => {
     MailApp.sendEmail(e, subject, message);
  });
}
```

If you wish to attach this to an onEdit you will have to rethink the process because the onEdit trigger fires on every edit to any sheet and most likely you will be require to use an installable onEdit so that you can perform operations that require permission.  I'd recommend you play around with the onEdit simple trigger for a while.  Look at the event object and see what's available at low overhead cost.